# newcommand with variable number of arguments

Tags: macros, conditionals, parameters

I have seen several related questions, but none seems to address specifically this.

I would like to define a command that accepts a variable number of arguments. Something like

```
\newcommand{\func}(1){\if{#1}{f(#1)}{f}}
```

So that if there is a parameter the output will be `f(#1)` and if there is no parameter the output will be `f`, and never `f()`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, through the use of optional arguments. Check out the `xparse` package.

Comment: How about using a counter?

Comment: Have a look at the `pgfkeys` package. It lets you define commands with a _key=value_ API.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen While I don't quite know how a K/V interface would fit here, the `l3keys` package of the `expl3` bundle is also quite nice. :)

Comment: I can't really see the advantage of writing `\func{1}` instead of `\func(1)`.

Comment: @egreg convention, how can that be done?

Comment: @SeanAllred You can have a key that specifies the number of arguments, a key/value for first argument, a key/value for second argument, and so on. For example, `[arguments=3,argument 1=a, argument 2=b, argument 3=c]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `xparse` package allows for some really cool syntax stuff.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand\funcF{d()}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{f(#1)}{f}}

% This is a version that follows more popular LaTeX syntax conventions.
\NewDocumentCommand\NormalFuncF{o}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{f(#1)}{f}}

\begin{document}
\[ \funcF(2) = 4       \]
\[ \funcF              \]
\[ \NormalFuncF[2] = 4 \]
\[ \NormalFuncF        \]
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: The parser allows `()` delimited arguments but in LaTeX2e `()` arguments should be used with picture coordinates.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Fair—It should be noted that *normal* syntax rules would follow that `{}` and `[]` conventions. I'll edit-in a version that follows this.

Comment: `()` delimited arguments fit perfectly with the OP question because of the semantics. They do not conflict with the picture usage. Moreover, they make typing much more natural and refactoring a lot easier because of the `xparse` ability to properly balance delimiters:
\NewDocumentCommand \FuncF { d() } {
  \IfValueTF { #1 } {
    f \mathord{ \left( #1 \right) }
  } {
    f
  }
}
\\[
\FuncF( \sin^2(x) )
\\]

Answer (score 6):

Optional arguments should use `[]` so

```
\newcommand{\func}[1][]{f\ifx\relax#1\relax\else(#1)\fi}
```

Used as

`\func`  or `\func[x]`

Comment: Is the `\ifx` structure how you test for a value with 'normal' TeX? (Also, shouldn't there be a `\fi`?)

Comment: @SeanAllred a `\fi` might be useful, thanks:-)

Comment: @SeanAllred if `#1` is empty it is `\ifx\relax\relax` which is true, otherwise it is false (`\relax` there can be any command that you do not expect in the argument)