# How do you create a variadic new command?

Tags: macros, renewcommand, def

The word "***variadic***" is used for functions, and commands, which can accept any number of input arguments.

---

Below, we see an example of a custom command which has three inputs:

```tex
\newcommand{\mycmd}[3]{ {{e^{#1}}^{#2}}^{#3}}

\mycmd{1}{2}{3}
```

[image: screen capture of ((e^1)^2)^3]

The problem is, the command I provided some small amount of source code for always has exactly three inputs.

How do we create a variadic command which allows 0 inputs, 1 input, 2 inputs, 3 inputs, etc?

---

| NUMBER OF INPUTS | CALL OR INVOCATION | PICTURE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | `\mycmd` | [image: picture of the letter "e" with no exponent] |
| 1 | `\mycmd{1}` | [image: picture of SOMTHING] |
| 2 | `\mycmd{1}{2}` | [image: picture of SOMTHING] |
| 3 | `\mycmd{1}{2}{3}` | [image: picture of something] |

Comment: Don't do it in the way you showed here. Better use `\mycmd`, `\mycmd[1]`, `\mycmd[1, 2]`, `\mycmd[1, 2, 3]`, etc.

Comment: BTW, the order of operations means that it should be typed and evaluated as `e^{1^{2^3}}`

Comment: Looks like someone (not me) downvoted the question, because there are other questions with similar purpose, answered.

Comment: @rallg Though it is not always easy to find things and nothing looks likely of the links on the right, so you might want to include a pointer?

Comment: The search term should be "variable number of arguments". For example, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174847/newcommand-with-variable-number-of-arguments

Answer (score 2):

The following implements the argument structure as lain out in my comment, considering also the side note made by @Teepeemm.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \mycmd { O{} }
  {
    e
    \clist_map_function:nN {#1} \__idlecustard_exponent_chain:nw
    \use_none:n \__idlecustard_exponent_chain_mark:
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__idlecustard_exponent_chain:nw
    #1 #2 \__idlecustard_exponent_chain_mark:
  { \sp { #1 #2 \__idlecustard_exponent_chain_mark: } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
$\mycmd$

$\mycmd[1]$

$\mycmd[1, 2]$

$\mycmd[1, 2, 3]$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are tens of question on the site asking for “commands with a variable number of arguments”. You *may* do it, but it's best not to.

A syntax such as `\cmd[1,2,3]` is much simpler.

Here there's the slight complication that you need to brace every exponent: you need to get

```
e^{1^{2^{3}}}
```

but we can exploit the fact that `\bgroup` and `\egroup` are perfectly safe in this situation in place of braces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycmd}{o}
 {
  e\IfValueT{#1}{\idle_exponents:n{#1}}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \idle_exponents:n
 {
  \clist_map_function:nN { #1 } \__idle_exponents:n
  \prg_replicate:nn { \clist_count:n { #1 } } { \egroup }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__idle_exponents:n
 {
  ^\bgroup\scriptstyle #1
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\mycmd+\mycmd[1]+\mycmd[1,2]+\mycmd[1,2,3]$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Just for academic interest:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycmd}{}
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l__idle_exponents_seq
  e\idle_exponents_gather:
 }

\seq_new:N \l__idle_exponents_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \idle_exponents_gather:
 {
  \peek_catcode:NTF \c_group_begin_token
   {
    \__idle_exponents_add:n
   }
   {
    \__idle_exponents_deliver:
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__idle_exponents_add:n
 {
  \seq_put_right:Nn \l__idle_exponents_seq { #1 }
  \idle_exponents_gather:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__idle_exponents_deliver:
 {
  \seq_map_function:NN \l__idle_exponents_seq \__idle_exponents:n
  \prg_replicate:nn { \seq_count:N \l__idle_exponents_seq } { \egroup }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__idle_exponents:n
 {
  ^\bgroup\scriptstyle #1
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\mycmd+\mycmd{1}+\mycmd{1}{2}+\mycmd{1}{2}{3}$

\end{document}
```